# Error in the test class: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I cannot get rid of the "Cannot find symbol" error where it says "newEmployee.calcWTax(grossPay);" in the test class.

I have looked at many threads and I know it has something to do with the fact that grossPay isn't declared but I can't figure out where.

Also, as a side note, anything in a comment in a parameter or method is because I'm not sure if I'm going to use it or not yet.

```
/*
Test class to test Employee.java 
*/

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EmployeeTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Scanner input = newScanner(System.in);
//gets ID number of employee
    Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the ID number of the employee?");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(input);
    newEmployee.setID(id);  
//gets wage of employee
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the wage of this employee?");
    double wage = Double.parseDouble(input);
    newEmployee.setWage(wage);
//gets hours worked of employee
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many hours did this employee work?");
    double hours = Double.parseDouble(input);
    newEmployee.setHours(hours);

//calculates and displays gross pay
newEmployee.calcGrossPay(hours, wage);
System.out.println(newEmployee.displayPay());

//calculates and displays withholding tax
newEmployee.calcWTax(grossPay);
System.out.println(newEmployee.displayTax());
    }

}
```

And this is the Employee.java:

```
public class Employee
{
    //private String name;
    private double wage;
    private int id;
    private double hours;
    private double grossPay;
    private double tax;
    private double netPay;


    public Employee(/*String aName*/)
    {
        //aName = name;
        wage = 0;
        id = 0;
        hours = 0;
        }
    public Employee(/*String aName,*/double aWage, int aID, double aHours)
    {
        //aName = name;
        aWage = wage;
        aID = id;
        aHours = hours;
        }

//mutators
    public void setID(int aID)
    {
        int newID = aID + id;
        id = newID;
    }
    /*public void setName(String aName)
    {
        String newName = aName;
        name = newName;
        }*/
    public void setWage(double aWage)
    {
        double newWage = aWage + wage;
        newWage = wage;
        }
    public void setHours(double aHours)
    {
        double newHours = aHours + hours;
        newHours = hours;
        }
    public void setGross(double aGross)
    {
        double newGross = aGross + grossPay;
        newGross = grossPay;
        }

//Accessors
    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
        }
    /*public String getName()
    {
        return name;
        }*/
    public double getWage()
    {
        return wage;
        }
    public double getHours()
    {
        return hours;
        }

//Computes gross pay
    public double calcGrossPay(double hours, double wage)
{
    if ( hours > 40 )
      {
      double extraHours = hours - 40;
      grossPay = ( 40 * wage ) + ( extraHours * (wage * 1.5) );
      }
    else grossPay = hours * wage;

    return grossPay;
}

//Displays gross pay
public double displayPay()
{
    return grossPay;
    }
//calculates Withholding tax
public double calcWTax(double gross)
{
    gross = grossPay;
    if (grossPay >= 0)
    {
        if (grossPay >= 0 && grossPay <= 300)
        {
            double wTax = grossPay * .1;
            wTax = tax;
            }
        else if (grossPay >= 300.01 && grossPay <= 400)
        {
            double wTax = grossPay * .12;
            wTax = tax;
            }
        else if (grossPay >=400.01 && grossPay <= 500)
        {
            double wTax = grossPay * .15;
            wTax = tax;
            }
        else if (grossPay >=500.01)
        {
            double wTax = grossPay * .2;
            wTax = tax;
            }
        else
        System.out.println("Error: Gross Pay is below 0");
        }
    else
    System.out.println("You haven't earned any money, get to work!");

    return tax;
    }

//displays withholding tax
public double displayTax()
{
    return tax;
    }
//calculates Net Pay
public double calcNetPay()
{
    double newNet = grossPay - tax;
    newNet = netPay;

    return netPay;
    }

//displays Net Pay
public double displayNet()
{
    return netPay;
    }


}
```

Comment: don't forget to post the error messages on these type of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive the return value from `calcGrossPay` method and pass it to the `calcWTax` method.

Declare the return value of `calcGrossPay` in a variable named `grossPay` and use it.

```
double grossPay = newEmployee.calcGrossPay(hours, wage);
System.out.println(newEmployee.displayPay());

//calculates and displays withholding tax
newEmployee.calcWTax(grossPay);
```

---

```
  public double calcWTax(double gross)
  {
    gross = grossPay;
```

This should be like this `grossPay = gross`. The input parameter you might be want to set to the class member not the other way round.

```
  public double calcWTax(double gross) {
  grossPay = gross
```

Comment: wow, I seriously can't believe I missed that. Such a simple solution to such a headache I had. Yet another reason why I should wait until last-minute to do assignments. Thank you so much, I would have been staring at this forever.

Answer (score 0):

Your method calcGrossPay() returns the gross pay.  You can store it for use a few lines later by assigning it to a variable I'll conveniently name grossPay.

```
double grossPay = newEmployee.calcGrossPay(hours, wage);
System.out.println(newEmployee.displayPay());

//calculates and displays withholding tax
newEmployee.calcWTax(grossPay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a variable `grossPay` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`grossPay` is a variable of `Employee` Class not a variable of `EmployeeTest` class. so Use `newEmployee.calcGrossPay(hours,wage)` instead of `grossPay`